# How to visualize optimization problems' feasible region?

Tags: visualization, optimization, graphical-model, linear-models

Is there any tool to visualize the feasible region when given a set of Linear equations (equalities and inequalities). If not, can anyone suggest a way to visualize it?
If I am going to do it myself using Python, which libraries should I use. I have found sympy, but I couldn't get it to draw inequalities nor draw the intersections only.

I have also found wolfram, but I could only see pre-built visualizations and not visualize my own system.

Can I use Gurobi itself to show me what it is doing graphically?

I know it is a very basic question, but I am a beginner in this area so go easy on me

Answer (score 3):

You can plot the feasible region with python matplotlib and numpy libraries.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


d = np.linspace(-2,16,300)
x,y = np.meshgrid(d,d)
plt.imshow( ((y>=2) & (2*y<=25-x) & (4*y>=2*x-8) & (y<=2*x-5)).astype(int) , 
                extent=(x.min(),x.max(),y.min(),y.max()),origin="lower", cmap="Greys", alpha = 0.3);

x = np.linspace(0, 16, 2000)
# y >= 2
y1 = (x*0) + 0
# 2y <= 25 - x
y2 = (25-x)/2.0
# 4y >= 2x - 8 
y3 = (2*x-8)/4.0
# y <= 2x - 5 
y4 = 2 * x -5

plt.plot(x, 2*np.ones_like(y1))
plt.plot(x, y2, label=r'$2y\leq25-x$')
plt.plot(x, y3, label=r'$4y\geq 2x - 8$')
plt.plot(x, y4, label=r'$y\leq 2x-5$')
plt.xlim(0,16)
plt.ylim(0,11)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
plt.xlabel(r'$x$')
plt.ylabel(r'$y$')
```

output:

[image]

Also you can check this [post](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/2862/tool-editor-to-visualize-optimization-problem-files-and-solutions) on Operations Research Stack Exchange about how to visualize optimization problems. They use Lingo, GCG, MIPLIB, strIPlib you can choose. I use python because with this I can adjust my environment for Pyomo.

References:

[An introduction to linear programming in python](https://paulminogue.com/index.php/2020/07/20/an-introduction-to-linear-programming-in-python/)
[Tool/Editor to visualize optimization problem files and solutions](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/2862/tool-editor-to-visualize-optimization-problem-files-and-solutions)

Answer (score 1):

For Wolfram Language you may use [`ImplicitRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion.html), [`ContourPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html), and [`RegionPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot.html).

For a `system`

```
system =
  {
   y >= 2
   , 2 y <= 25 - x
   , 4 y >= 2 x - 8
   , y <= 2 x - 5
   };
```

The `ImplicitRegion` and its [`RegionBounds`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionBounds.html) (useful for plotting) can be obtained with

```
fregion = ImplicitRegion[system, {x, y}];
rbounds = RegionBounds@fregion;
plotbounds = Transpose[{.9, 1.1} Transpose@rbounds];
```

`fregion` can be used with all [Region Properties and Measures](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/GeometricPropertiesAndMeasures.html) if you need addtional information on the feasible region.

The inequalities of `system` can be `ContourPlot`ed by [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html)ing [`Equal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html). [`Evaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html) is used to resolve the expressions before the passing them to `ContourPlot`; only needed because converting the inequalities and determining the bounds on the fly.

```
frplot =
 Show[
  ContourPlot[
   Evaluate[Equal @@@ system]
   , Evaluate[Sequence @@ MapThread[Prepend, {plotbounds, {x, y}}]]
   , PlotLegends -> system
   , AspectRatio -> Automatic
   ]
  , RegionPlot[fregion, BoundaryStyle -> None]
  ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

We can check a couple of objection function solutions.

```
objectives = {x y, x - 2 y};
sols = Maximize[{#, system}, {x, y}] & /@ objectives
```

> ```
> {{625/8, {x->25/2, y->25/4}}, {4, {x->8, y->2}}}
> ```

[`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html) with [`Callout`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Callout.html) labels.

```
splot =
 ListPlot[
  MapIndexed[
   Callout[{x, y} /. Last@#, "Max" <> ToString@objectives[[#2]]] &, 
   sols]
  ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Then [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html) the plots together.

```
Show[frplot, splot]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.